# Whether the io buffer will be automatically emptied when the program crashes？

Tags: c++11, io, buffer

Let's talk about c++ programming, whether the IO buffer will be automatically cleared when the program crashes？if not, then there must be some considerations behind that, what's the reason?

```cpp
cout << "some text";
// here our program crashed unexpected, whether the IO buffer will be automatically cleared?
doSomethingThatCrashTheProgram();
```

Is the IO buffer shared memory or space allocated by each program individually?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in `doSomethingThatCrashTheProgram()`. If you are not in control of that function (which seems unlikely), your program is probably displaying some sort of undefined behavior.

With [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) you are on the wrong track expecting *anything*. The program may flush, clear or even summon [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

It will not.

This is why the C `stderr` and the C++ `cerr` IO channels are unbuffered. That way the error log statements get out to the user as soon as they are written, so that a later crash does not hide them.

If you have a core dump file, with enough effort you can locate the IO buffer and see what's in there.

The reason behind not flushing the buffer is simple: It is a crash! The program did something wrong and got killed for it. Is the operating system supposed to step in and poke through the shards of the possibly corrupt program memory to find the IO buffer? That is too much to ask.